# Using Point-to-Site and an Azure AD User Account, how do I access an Azure VM that is AzureADjoined?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have created a VM in Azure as mentioned below

```
resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine_hub" {
  name                = "vm-hub"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg.location
  size                = "Standard_B8ms"
  admin_username      = "xxxxx"
  admin_password      = "xxxxx"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.virtual_machine_hub_nic.id
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
    offer     = "Windows-10"
    sku       = "21h1-pro"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_network_interface.virtual_machine_hub_nic
  ]    
}
```

and enabled the AADLoginForWindows extension

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "virtual_machine_hub_ext" {
  name                 = "AADLoginForWindows"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.virtual_machine_hub.id
  type                       = "AADLoginForWindows"
  type_handler_version       = "1.0"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version = true
  publisher                  = "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.virtual_machine_hub
  ] 
}
```

and it is AzureADConnected

[image]

My Azure user account is given access on the VM using RBAC

[image]

Now, the client machine (laptop) is connected to another domain in Azure AD (say, demo.com) as well as DomainJoined.

[image]

I am using the Azure VPN client to connect to the Azure Network using Point-to-Site.

While trying to RDP into the VM, it is falling with the below error message

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I also get the same error like below***

[image]

To resolve this issue:

Try to allow system properties like below:

[image]

Try to add the user to rdp group via cmd like below:

```json
net localgroup "Remote Desktop Users" /add "AzureAD\xx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com"
Get-LocalGroupMember -Name "Remote Desktop users"
```

[image]

In your local machine try to modify the rdp file in order to authenticate with different user:

Right click on downloaded Rdp file -> Open with note pad try to add bottom line like below:

```json
enablecredsspsupport:i:0
authentication level:i:2
```

[image]

Now double click on rdp file try to connect like below:

use **`.\AzureAD\email@company.com`** or **`AzureAD\email@company.com`**

[image]

Orelse, In your virtual machine -> run command under operation -> disable NLA -> Run

[image]

Reference:

[Remote Desktop to Azure AD Joined Computer – Bradley Schacht](https://bradleyschacht.com/remote-desktop-to-azure-ad-joined-computer/) *By Bradley Schacht*

Comment: Is it safe to Disable NLA?